# Everything now is XML - but programming is still done with some legacy files obeying complicated syntax

Tags: xml, programming-languages

Why is this ? Gcc is now providing a "C-to-XML" conversion since XML is more easily parsed.

Couldn't we benefit if our source code was XML?

Of course, nobody want's to edit XML files manually - but that's what IDEs are made for.

- Would some programming language with less syntax (LISP, Smalltalk) better map to XML?

Comment: actually, nobody wants to edit java sources manually, either.

Comment: If you have a feasible suggestion for a way to program in XML, I'd love to see it!

Comment: Can anyone hear a question being closed?

Comment: @Mitro: What the other comments mean is that you simply cannot RUN an XML file.  It is used to describe data, not to provide an executable piece of machine code.  In other words: XML is like the music coming from your iPod - without the machine around it, you won't hear a thing.  Having said that:  You can use XML to model an abstract syntax tree (AST) representing your program, which could later be parsed and translated into actual C.  That would still require in-depth knowledge of the C language, though, at least for whoever has to do the translation.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: You can't run a .c file either...

Comment: @Greg: Well, yeah, but you can compile it.  Now you say: But you could compile an XML file if you have the right compiler.  And then I say: go ahead and write one. ;)  Are we splitting hairs?

Comment: @weltraumpirat I don't get the difference: Of course, you cannot execute C. Even after compiling, it is just a file on your disk - data. The important step is when you present that file to your processor *as something to be executed*, or when you type `eval` into your favorite C interpreter. As an example, XSLT is both an XML dialect and a programming language (Turing complete and all that) - no matter if you are compiling them to C or to 8086 machine code - their semantics make them a programming language and not their presentation.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: That seems a strange argument. How is a compiler that compiles XML used to describe program into C or machine code different from a compiler that compiles C used to describe a program into machine code? The reason that there are so few XML-based programming language isn't that it's fundamentally impossible to program in an XML format, it's that XML is too verbose.

Comment: From a fundamental point of view, you are both right, of course.  I was being pragmatic - there just isn't an XML compiler yet.  But even if you wrote your program in XML, it would still have to have a syntax and semantics - you would have to define a schema to make sure your program is valid and can be compiled, which is pretty much the same thing: A set of conventions + rules that specifies in which way any piece of information written in your language should be interpreted.  You would get rid of points and braces and trade them for angle brackets and a large description of what means what.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <comment>
 <statement-of-argument>
    I don't think everything is XML.
 </statement-of-argument>
 <p>
    You still see plenty of plain text and other forms of encoding.  
    I think you're just being <pejorative>silly</pejorative>.
    Or perhaps imagining things.
 </p>
 </comment>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Couldn't we benefit if our source code was XML?

Let me take this question in its broader sense: suppose that our favorite programming language had a standard machine-readable form that admitted only well-formed trees.  Couldn't we benefit?

1. It was done with Ada in the 1980s, with a standard form for abstract-syntax trees (I believe it was called DIANA).  There was a modest benefit for those writing tools to analyze Ada.
2. Other experience gotten during the 1980s, with the Cornell Program Synthesizer and related tools, showed that for a developer, you *must* have the ability to edit a "thing" that is *not* a syntactically correct program.  Remember, [we are typists first, programmers second](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/we-are-typists-first-programmers-second.html), and what we learned from the Cornell Synthesizer experience was that using *any* IDE that forces you always to maintain a syntactically correct program (think: a well-formed XML tree) is like dragging around a ball and chain.

   **Good programmers are really, really good at typing text fast.**  Any representation or IDE which takes away that advantage had better offer some compelling compensating advantages.  For XML, I don't see what those compensating advantages might look like.
3. The one thing you gain with XML is that it's easier to write a parser.  (You still have to write one, but it's easier.)  But with the computing power we have gained since the 1980s, and with the plethora of new parsing techniques that can exploit that power, parsing (converting linear text to tree form) is just not that big a deal any more.  All of the work in creating great tools is in *analysis* (type checking, pointer analysis, information flow, optimization, you name it) of the resulting trees.  XML doesn't buy anything there.

I made my reputation working on compilers and related tools, and while I see some very modest benefits to having a standard representation of abstract-syntax trees, and would be willing to accept XML as such a representation, I can't see that the benefits would be worth the cost of agreeing on a standard.

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages are for programmers' convenience, not for ease of parsing.

Comment: I would say that they are^w should be convenient semantically, but their syntax is not too relevant. Actually, syntax is mostly annoying, and languages with less syntax are prettier.

Comment: Reading is much more important than writing. And this is where a decent syntax is really a key. Honestly, I am not eager to read tons of XML.

Answer (score 1):

Have fun with http://xplusplus.sourceforge.net/ :P